# error: The return type 'NetworkImage' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import '../models/post_model.dart';

Carousel(
        animationDuration: null,
          images: [
               ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: posts[index].MediaImage.length,
                          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return NetworkImage(posts[index].MediaImage[index].image);
                                }, ) ],) ,
```

I am trying to show multiple images from Network.
Does anybody know why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the following in your itemBuilder

```
return Image.network(posts[index].MediaImage[index].image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a ListView.builder inside of carousel, why would you even use that ??

Carousel expect NetworkImage only as a string of url and placing any other widget inside of that will land you to this error.

0

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import '../models/post_model.dart';

Carousel(
        animationDuration: null,
          images: [NetworkImage(posts[i].MediaImage[i].image.toString(),],) ,
```

This is the correct way , **.toString(),** is often required as NetworkImage expects a String.

If you have multiple images use :

```
for(int i =0;i<="please specify your length here", i++);
```

I have added `i` in place of index.

Carousel never takes anyother Widget than AssetImage or NetworkImage directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing from the way that Flutter names things, but [`NetworkImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) is an `ImageProvider`, not a `Widget` (which actually shows the image).  The widget you want is [`Image`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html), which can be constructed from an `ImageProvider`, or can be constructed from an URL directly via its [`Image.network` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html).